# netbeans ignore syntax checking

Tags: netbeans

In NetBeans (7.4) the syntax checker flags files, which contain errors, with a little red icon, which reflects up the directory path to the root. I have some Sass files that it doesn't seem to recognize.

Is there a way to disable scanning of certain files and/or directories so that the errors don't show?